# Is there any way to correct using socialshare links on localhost?

Tags: angularjs, django, facebook, web-services, django-rest-framework

I trying to add socialshare in my project, which run on localhost.
I using Django REST and Angular in frontend. And I used many ways to share page content, all doesn't works well. They shared only link to this page in my localhost.
Now I stoped on [720.angular-socialshare](https://github.com/720kb/angular-socialshare)
I trying to share only in [vk.com](http://vk.com) and [facebook.com](http://facebook.com)
Here is my page:

```
<div ng-controller="photoCtrl" class="photoCtrl">
    <img ng-src="{{ photo.img }}" alt="" class=" img-detail">
    <div class="row">
        {{ photo.text }}
    </div>
    <a href="#"
        socialshare
        socialshare-provider="vk"
        socialshare-text="{{ photo.text }}"
        socialshare-media="{{ photo.img }}">
        Share me on VK
    </a>
    <a href="#"
        socialshare
        socialshare-provider="facebook"
        socialshare-text="{{ photo.text }}"
        socialshare-media="{{ photo.img }}">
        Share me on Facebook
    </a>
</div>
```

I tryed to add `socialshare-url=""` property, like full locallhost url, and part of url, nothing changed.
here is controller for this page:

```
app.controller('photoCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$routeParams', 
 function($http, $scope, $routeParams){
   var photoId = $routeParams.photoId 
   $http.get('/api/photo/' + photoId + '/').success(function(data) {
   $scope.photo = data;
    });
  }
]);
```

`photoId` comes from my `model`, but it is not important.
Question is, can I use socialshare in my localhost or it will work only in real site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not share localhost URLs.

Facebook makes a request for the URL, to fetch the Open Graph meta data from it. Obviously, it can only do that, if the URL is publicly reachable on the internet.